# Using ElasticSearch from the browser fails on OPTIONS request

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, cors

I am using jQuery's `ajax` method to make a `POST` request to my Elastic's `_search` API.

When passing parameters in the query, all is good:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//localhost:9200/my_index/_search/?q=hello',
  method: 'POST'
}).then(function(body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

When passing parameters in the body (json), the problems start:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//localhost:9200/my_index/_search/',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: this.params
}).then(function(body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Instead of sending the `POST` request, the browser (Chrome) sends a `OPTIONS` request.

Reading jQuery's documentation I see:

> For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

So that's probably where it comes from.

The problem is, nothing happens after that preflight request.

Looking at the request itself in Wireshark:

```
OPTIONS /my_index/_search/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4000/search/?q=hello
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 07:30:50 GMT
content-length: 0
```

I noticed that the response's `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` field is empty, so I am thinking it may be related.

My **elasticsearch.yml** file contains:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

I added:

```
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

But it did not change anything.

Comment: What version of ES do you have? See this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17483

Comment: `version[2.3.1]` which version was it fixed on?

Comment: Will be fixed in [2.3.2](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17524)

Comment: aha - that would explain. Do you happen to know the ETA for this version?

Comment: (feel free to write this as an answer that I will accept)

Comment: There are [7 more issues](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/labels/v2.3.2) to fix, but it should be imminent. Next week probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17483) which has been fixed and will be released in [2.3.2](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17524)

Comment: And ES 2.3.2 is out today: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-2-3-2-released